# Hardcoded expected string vs extracted variable in React shallow test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I made two versions of the same simple test and I am looking for the better one. The only difference is that the first returns HTML code `<div>::name::</div>` and the second one - JSX `<div>{name}</div>`. I believe the goal of this kind of render test is to prove that the correct HTML is being returned from the render, so I believe the first approach is more accurate. Thoughts?

version 1:

```
const prop = {name: '::name::'}
const wrapper = shallow(<Component prop={prop} />)

expect(wrapper.equals(
  <div>
    <div>::name::</div>
  </div>
)).toEqual(true)
```

version 2:

```
const name = ::name::
const wrapper = shallow(<Component prop={name: name} />)

expect(wrapper.equals(
  <div>
    <div>{name}</div>
  </div>
)).toEqual(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

First thumb rule in React unit testing - **check only the conditionals**.

What that means is, when you pass a prop and just render the prop in a div, it will be rendered. You **don't** have to test if the same value you pass is rendered in the div because that is the library behaviour and React is already tested to render props values properly.

Instead, your test cases should focus on conditionals and your logic. For example

```
const Example = ({ isFoo }) => {
  return(
    <div>{isFoo ? <Foo /> : <Bar />}</div>
  );
};
```

Now this should be unit tested as

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Example isFoo={true} />);

expect(wrapper.contains('Foo')).toEqual(true);
expect(wrapper.contains('Bar')).toEqual(false);
```

*Note: syntax might vary but you get the gist.*

Comment: > You don't have to test if the same value you pass is rendered in the div because that is the library behaviour and React is already tested to render props values properly.

but you may want to test that you've typed the right variable in the JSX

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference since

1. `::name::` is still hardcoded
2. `.equals()` does not check if it's a reference to the same variable.

So there is still no way to validate if `name` is coming from props and not hard-coded equally to testing value.

It's better just update props in your test and ensure component is changed:

```
wrapper.setProps({prop: {name: 'anotherName'}});
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
```

BTW you better rely on [`toMatchSnapshot()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing) instead of comparing manually.